# Copy all files and subfolders having .csv extension into another new path with same folder hierarchy

Tags: python, os.path

Let's say I have various folders(abc,bcd,cde) in my source path(C:\) with different .csv files

```
C:\abc\test1.csv
C:\bcd\test2.json
C:\cde\test3.csv
```

Need to move folders with .csv to target path(D:\) as follows:

```
D:\abc\test1.csv
D:\cde\test3.csv
```

If no folder name(abc,cde) exists in target path, then it needs to be created.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now your question is a bit vague and reads like you just want someone to write your code. You might try reading some other questions/answers to see if you can answer your own question first. What have you tried so far (give code if you can)? Did it work? How deep is your directory structure? shutil and copytree might be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Pam, I came across many questions, but they were only about copying entire directory without any conditions. I tried shutil copytree but it has options only to ignore certain kind of extensions such as .txt,.csv etc. But in this case need only .csv to be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to define a recursive function that copies the directory level-by-level

```
import os
import shutil

def selective_copy(source_dir, target_dir, file_extension):
   if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
      os.makedirs(target_dir)

   for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
      source_fn = os.path.join(source_dir, item)
      if os.path.isdir(source_fn):
         selective_copy(source_fn, os.path.join(target_dir, item), file_extension)
      elif item.endswith(file_extension):
         shutil.copyfile(source_fn, os.path.join(target_dir, item))
```

If you want the directory structure to only be replicated if there are files to be copied from it, You can move the "if not os.path.exists(target_dir)" conditional to right before the "shutil.copyfile(...)"

Comment: Thank you soo much. it worked